# my innerHTML doesn't changes when i press the key

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote this code where the list item to be added stay in the top of the list, and the order should actualize the just like the variable, but it doens't change, it remains 1

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', addItem)

var order = 1;

var listItem = [""];
var listQuantity = [0];

var orderin = document.getElementById('order-register');
orderin.innerHTML = order;

function addItem() {
  let itemout, qttout, addrow;
  let table = document.getElementById('tabelaitens');
  let itemin = document.getElementById('itemin');
  let qttin = document.getElementById('qttin');
  let key = event.key;

  if (key == "Enter") {

    if (itemin.value != "") {
      itemout = itemin.value;
    } else {
      //add dropdown
    }

    if (qttin.value > 0) {
      qttout = qttin.value;
    } else {
      //add dropdown
    }

    if ((itemout != undefined) && (qttout != undefined)) {
      orderin.innerHTML = '' + order;
      addrow = "<td class=\"order\">" + order + "</td><td class=\"item\">" + itemout + "</td><td class=\"quantity\">" + qttout + "</td>";
      table.innerHTML += addrow;
      order++;
      orderin.innerHTML = order;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#tabelaitens {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

.linha,
.linharegister {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.order {
  width: 5%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  width: 85%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.quantity {
  width: 10%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

#order-register {
  text-align: center;
}

#order-register,
.item-register,
.quantity-register {
  padding: 5px
}

.item-register>input,
.item-register>input:focus,
.quantity-register>input,
.quantity-register>input:focus {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: solid rgb(196, 183, 164);
}

.quantity-register>input {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Lista de Compras</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="img/list.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styletable.css">

  <script src="javascript/addlist.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>

  <main>
    <ul>
      <h1>
        <li id="listname">lista</li>
      </h1>
    </ul>

    <table id="tabelaitens">

      <tr class="linha">
        <td class="order">Ordem</td>
        <td class="item">Item</td>
        <td class="quantity">Quantidade</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="linharegister">
        <form>
          <td id="order-register">PH</td>
          <td class="item-register"><input id="itemin" type="text" name="itemregister" autocomplete="off"></td>
          <td class="quantity-register"><input id="qttin" type="number" name="itemregister" autocomplete="off" min="1"></td>
        </form>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </main>

</body>
```

I tried make the var turn into a let, put the value in innerHTML outside the if, and a lot of small things that didn't changed anything at all. I dont know if it is an error in the syntax, logic or whatever, but one thing is right, there is no ";" missing.

Comment: *"I dont know if it is an error in the syntax, logic or whatever"* - Then now would be a good time to find out.  When you open your browser's debugging tools and look at the console, are there any errors at all?  When you step through the code in your browser's script debugger, what specifically happens and what specifically fails?

Comment: `addrow` needs to have `<tr>` around it.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating invalid HTML because you don't have `<tr>` around the new row that you're adding. The browser is trying to fix it, but it ends up putting the added row at the beginning instead of the end. Add this and you get the desired result.

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', addItem)

var order = 1;

var listItem = [""];
var listQuantity = [0];

var orderin = document.getElementById('order-register');
orderin.innerHTML = order;

function addItem() {
  let itemout, qttout, addrow;
  let table = document.getElementById('tabelaitens');
  let itemin = document.getElementById('itemin');
  let qttin = document.getElementById('qttin');
  let key = event.key;

  if (key == "Enter") {

    if (itemin.value != "") {
      itemout = itemin.value;
    } else {
      //add dropdown
    }

    if (qttin.value > 0) {
      qttout = qttin.value;
    } else {
      //add dropdown
    }

    if ((itemout != undefined) && (qttout != undefined)) {
      addrow = "<tr><td class=\"order\">" + order + "</td><td class=\"item\">" + itemout + "</td><td class=\"quantity\">" + qttout + "</td><tr>";
      table.innerHTML += addrow;
      order++;
      orderin.innerHTML = order;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#tabelaitens {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

.linha,
.linharegister {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.order {
  width: 5%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  width: 85%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.quantity {
  width: 10%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

#order-register {
  text-align: center;
}

#order-register,
.item-register,
.quantity-register {
  padding: 5px
}

.item-register>input,
.item-register>input:focus,
.quantity-register>input,
.quantity-register>input:focus {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: solid rgb(196, 183, 164);
}

.quantity-register>input {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Lista de Compras</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="img/list.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styletable.css">

  <script src="javascript/addlist.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>

  <main>
    <ul>
      <h1>
        <li id="listname">lista</li>
      </h1>
    </ul>

    <table id="tabelaitens">

      <tr class="linha">
        <td class="order">Ordem</td>
        <td class="item">Item</td>
        <td class="quantity">Quantidade</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="linharegister">
        <form>
          <td id="order-register">PH</td>
          <td class="item-register"><input id="itemin" type="text" name="itemregister" autocomplete="off"></td>
          <td class="quantity-register"><input id="qttin" type="number" name="itemregister" autocomplete="off" min="1"></td>
        </form>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </main>

</body>
```